# Executing form with JS on tag <a>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I found similar questions here, but not what i'm looking for.
I want to send form, when clicking on html tag `<a>`, with java script. My problem is that I don't know where I put the name, so I can use php isset function later.
This is what I did, but it's not working:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
      echo "Test Kappa 123";
   }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?=$site_link?>user/<?=$username?>" id="form_options">
   <a href="javascript:void();" name="test" onclick="document.getElementById('form_options').submit();"> Radnom text </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the value in a `hidden` input field like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    echo "Test Kappa 123";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?=$site_link?>user/<?=$username?>" id="form_options">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test value" />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form_options').submit(); return false"> Radnom text </a>
</form>
```

Note: I made a number of changes from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Forms only submit values in `<button>`, `<input>` and `<textarea>`, not `<a>`. You should make that link into a button, then you don't even have to use javascript.

Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$site_link?>user/<?=$username?>" id="form_options">
    <button name="test" type="submit" value="test">Radnom text</button>
</form>
```

If you don't want it to look like a button. You can use this css to remove the background and border:

```
<style>
    button {
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }   
</style>
```

Comment: I tryed to do it this way, but I have to do so much work to remove the button style. It worked with the hidden input. Thanks anyway!